# Spring DATA, создание кастомного метода

Tags: java, spring, controller, repository

Есть у нас репозиторий со стандартными функциями :

```
save
findOne
exists
findAll
count
delete
deleteAll
```

Мне нужно добавить новую, поиск по логину. И я не могу понять, как правильно это создать. Поискал в интернете, но мало что понял. Делал, как написано здесь http://devcolibri.com/4149
Вот сущность:

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String password;

    @Column(length = 2)
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    public Room getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(Room room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public User() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
}
```

Частица кода из контролера:

```
.....
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUserByName(@PathVariable("name") String userLogin){
        return userService.getByLogin(userLogin);
    }
.....
```

И репозиторий

```
package ua.samuliak.messenger.repository;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import ua.samuliak.messenger.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    @Query("FROM User WHERE login = :name ")
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

Помогите с репозиторием, пожалуйста! Как сделать правильно запрос на поиск по имени, что бы возвращало сущность ?

Я немного неправильно выразился, ошибки как таковой нет, просто сам запрос подчеркнут (прилягаю скрин) и пишет "FROM" unexpected. И при запросе на сервер (смотрите код с контролером) он не выдает пользователя по логину а пишет такую ошибку (скрин №2).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новая проблема

```
31-May-2016 11:08:59.847 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-35] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.] with root cause
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for parameter binding must not be null or empty! For named parameters you need to use @Param for query method parameters on Java versions < 8.
```

Comment: а что у вас,собственно, не работает?

Comment: ссориться на запрос в репозиторие (

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, стактрейс ошибки. тогда мы вам обязательно поможем :)

Comment: добавил в низ главного поста )

Comment: У вас проблема не с репозиторием, а с контроллером, о чем спринг вас любезно информирует, скорее всего у вас есть второй контроллер опирающийся на похожий путь, спринг не знает какой из них выбрать и ругается - проверьте.

в частности для спринга не очевидна разница между 

url'ом в вашем методе getUserById и методе getUserByName

Comment: Уже такой ошибки нет, но есть другая проблема. Не выводит JSON, как когда вывожу весь список. И вот такая ошибка вылетает в логкете (добавил в главный пост)

Comment: добавьте @Param("name") к параметру метода в репозиторий, получится что то вроде User findByName(@Param("name") String name), либо дебажьте и удостоверьтесь что спринг корректно вытягивает имя из @PathVariable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас проблема не с репозиторием, а с контроллером, о чем спринг вас любезно информирует. у вас есть второй контроллер опирающийся на похожий путь, спринг не знает какой из них выбрать и ругается.

в частности для спринга не очевидна разница между url'ом в вашем методе

- getUserById

  и методе
- getUserByName